# Why did Prophet SAW get angry from the question he was asked in Sahih al-Bukhari 20?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

[Sahih al-Bukhari 20:](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/2/13)

> **Narrated 'Aisha:**
>
> Whenever Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) ordered the Muslims to do something, he
> used to order them deeds which were easy for them to do, (according to
> their strength and endurance). They said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! We
> are not like you. Allah has forgiven your past and future sins." So
> Allah's Apostle became angry and it was apparent on his face. He said,
> "I am the most Allah fearing, and know Allah better than all of you
> do."

**Why is the Prophet SAW getting angry  from the question people asked him? And why is he replying in a way he replied in the hadith? What does one learn from this hadith?**

Answer (score 1):

He became angry because of what they were inadvertently implying: that there was good that the Prophet (SAW) refrained from doing because his sins were forgiven and he was guaranteed Jannah.

As the Prophet (SAW) said, this was not the case. Not making things difficult for yourself and for others beyond their capabilities is part of the religion. Making it harder for yourself than you can bear has no benefit. If it did, the Prophet himself would have done it first even if his sins were forgiven.